verify authorization telegram not equal hash nodejs
I'm encountering an issue with verifying Telegram authorization. Specifically:

The auth_data payload I receive from window.getUser.
{
    "query_id": "AAHOmFBD....",
    "user": {
        "id": 1129355470,
        "first_name": "Khoai",
        "last_name": "",
        "username": "khoai1187",
        "language_code": "en",
        "allows_write_to_pm": true
    },
    "auth_date": "1724830118",
    "hash": "0d60d08d1058d2da0d90d67fe177e8e1d..."
}


I have mapped the auth_data as follows:
{
        "auth_date": "1724830118",
        "first_name": "Khoai",
        "id": 1129355470,
        "username": "khoai1187",
        "hash": "0d60d08d1058d2da0d90d67fe177e8e1d..."
}


I followed the code instructions provided by Telegram documentation, but after creating the HMAC, the resulting value does not match the hash of the auth_data received from Telegram.
const checkTelegramAuthorization = (authData) => {
  try {
    logger.info('checkTelegramAuthorization START', authData);
    const BOT_TOKEN = '7343419643...';
    const checkHash = authData.hash;
    console.log(" ~ checkTelegramAuthorization ~ checkHash:", checkHash)
    delete authData.hash;

    let dataCheckArray = [];
    for (let key in authData) {
      dataCheckArray.push(`${key}=${authData[key]}`);
    }
    dataCheckArray.sort();
    const data_check_string = dataCheckArray.join('\n');
    const secretKey = crypto.createHmac("sha256", "WebAppData").update(BOT_TOKEN);
    logger.info('secret_key:', secretKey);

    const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secretKey.digest()).update(data_check_string).digest('hex');
    console.log(" ~ checkTelegramAuthorization ~ hash:", hash)

    if (hash !== checkHash) {
      return false
    }

    if ((Date.now() - authData.auth_date) > 86400) {
      return false
    }

    return true;

  } catch (error) {
    logger.error("checkTelegramAuthorization ERROR", error);
    return false;
  }

}



At that point, the values after logging are:
checkTelegramAuthorization START: {"auth_date":"1724830118","first_name":"Khoai","id":1129355470,"username":"khoai1187","hash":"0d60d08d1058d2da0d90d67fe177e8e1d65604d68cc0a3546c31463d0c28c08b"}
checkHash: 0d60d08d1058d2da0d90d67fe177e8e1d...
checkTelegramAuthorization ~ hash: e5b90d285d2b267ee94cb990b84f8a0d2...

Has anyone experienced a similar issue and found a solution?

Based on Telegram's documentation, the entire user object needs to be included as a single JSON string, not by extracting and using its individual keys. Therefore, you should convert the user object to a JSON string before adding it to the dataCheckString.

Data-check-string is a chain of all received fields, sorted alphabetically, in the format key= with a line feed character ('\n', 0x0A) used as separator – e.g., 'auth_date=<auth_date>\nquery_id=<query_id>\nuser='.

  const keys = Array.from(authData.keys()).sort();

  const dataCheckStrings = [];
    keys.forEach(key => 
    {
      if (key !== 'hash') 
      {
        let value = initData[key];

      if (typeof value === 'object')
      {
         value = JSON.stringify(value);
      }

      dataCheckStrings.push(`${key}=${value}`);
    }
  });
  const dataCheckString = dataCheckStrings.join('\n');

data_check_string will be like this:
auth_date=123123123
query_id=AAGlhC4DASDVDFTRHTHJTY
user={"id":2200863435,"first_name":"test","last_name":"Test","language_code":"en","allows_write_to_pm":true}

